# How to go from Vue to Nuxt?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I have a quick question regarding Nuxtjs and vue js. Currently I have a project in vuejs but as the vue js does not provide ssr functionality and I have some pages in the project on which the SEO matter a lot. To achieve this i have to use nuxt js for certain pages. So my question is that , how i am gonna configure nuxt js in current vue js project

Comment: I think you can't, Nuxtjs is a framework and expects that things like routing are made with their tools  

Try https://dev.to/ngranja19/how-to-migrate-a-vuejs-project-to-nuxtjs-in-8-steps-41dm

Comment: @MauroInsacco you can make your own router in Nuxt too. You are not obliged to use any convention of Nuxt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create a Nuxt Project.
2. Create a directory store and copy your store files into it.  In case you had split your store in modules you can follow the [instructions](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/directory-structure/store).
3. Create a directory Components and copy your components to it. For further information follow the link
   [follow the link](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/directory-structure/components/)
4. Create a page directory and copy your main pages to the page directory. Replace router-link by NuxtLink. For further information follow the link.
   [Click Here](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/get-started/routing/)
5. App a plugin directory. Follow the official instruction.
   [Official documentation about how to use plugins](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/directory-structure/plugins#vue-plugins)
6. Change the way you fetch data from server. Use **Fectch** and **asyncData** methods to **fetch** data from server.

[About Fetch and asyncData](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/features/data-fetching)

Finally you can configure you nuxt.config.js file for some external resources.

[Further Information about nuxt.config.js](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/directory-structure/nuxt-config#nuxtconfigjs)

Your Final Project should look like this:
[image: Your Final Project should look like this]

Answer (score 0):

You can change Vue into Nuxt pretty easily. Here is a video guide made by Debbie who previously worked as a Nuxt member: https://youtu.be/_eyGtBjNS4c

You can achieve pretty much the exact same setup in Nuxt as what you do currently have in Vue.